# Django - manage error with full_clean() validaton

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I use modelformset_factory, and I use full_clean() to validate the form with unique_together=True. I wonder what is the best way to handle error in case the unique_together do not validate in order to return the error message in the template.

Please take a look to my view, and tell me if im correct the way I do it, or if there is a better approach.

model:

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    shapefile = models.ForeignKey(Shapefile)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    type = models.IntegerField()
    width = models.IntegerField()
    precision = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def delete(self):
        shapefile = self.shapefile
        feature_selected = Feature.objectshstore.filter(shapefile=shapefile)
        feature_selected.hremove('attribute_value', self.name)
        super(Attribute, self).delete()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('name', 'shapefile'),)
```

form:

```
class AttributeForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttributeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
            self.fields['type'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
            self.fields['type'].required = False
            self.fields['width'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
            self.fields['precision'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True


    def clean_type(self):
        if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
            return self.instance.type
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['type']

    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FIELD_TYPE)

    class Meta:
        model = Attribute
        exclude = 'shapefile'
```

view:

```
def editFields(request, shapefile_id):
    layer_selected = Shapefile.objects.get(pk=shapefile_id)
    attributes_selected= Attribute.objects.filter(shapefile__pk=shapefile_id)
    attributesFormset = modelformset_factory(Attribute, form=AttributeForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)
    if request.POST:
        formset = attributesFormset(request.POST, queryset=attributes_selected)
        if formset.is_valid():
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                instance.shapefile = layer_selected
                try:
                    instance.full_clean()
                except ValidationError as e:
                    non_field_errors = e.message_dict[NON_FIELD_ERRORS]
                    print non_field_errors
                    formset = attributesFormset(queryset=attributes_selected)
                    return render_to_response("basqui/manage_layer_editFields.html", {'shapefile': layer_selected, 'formset':formset}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
                instance.save()

    formset = attributesFormset(queryset=attributes_selected)
    return render_to_response("basqui/manage_layer_editFields.html", {'shapefile': layer_selected, 'formset':formset}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the line `instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)`. After calling the superclass' `__init__` method you can just use `self.instance`, although its value may be None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disadvantage of your approach is that you have moved the validation from the form to the view.

I had the same problem recently of validating a unique together constraint where one field is excluded from the model form. My solution was to override the model form's `clean` method, and query the database to check the unique together constraint. This duplicates the code that is called by `full_clean`, but I like it because it's explicit.

I briefly thought about overriding [`_get_validation_exclusions`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L349) which would have been more DRY, but I decided not to rely on a private api.